# Matplotlib animated subplots using multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to compare several numerical schemes with exact solution of a PDE. To do that, I'm trying to make an animation, in which there are multiple subplots and each subplot has two functions evolving. (numerical and exact)

I found out how to make multiple lines animating here,
[Matplotlib multiple animate multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049762/matplotlib-multiple-animate-multiple-lines)

And I also found out how to make multiple subplots.
[animated subplots using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832055/animated-subplots-using-matplotlib)

But I'm not sure how to do both. They looks so confusing when looked together (I'm not that familiar with matplotlib, especially FuncAnimation)
And also I want to make a subplot number as variable, so user can input any number of functions.

my code is this. Currently this code generates plot for each numerical scheme, but I want it to make only one plot. 
So the 'plot' function would be called only once,

```
plot(*arguments, FTCS, upwind, anotherfunc, anotherfunc2, ...)
```

this way.

Sorry for the messy code. I attached all of them just to make 
a minimum working example. Only 'plot' function is relevant to my question.

*edited code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation



#dt=1/5
dx=1/400
tm=9
xm=1
C=0.8
u=.1
dt=dx*C/u
arguments=dt,dx,tm,xm,C

def plot(dt,dx,tm,xm,C,*funcs):
    plt.figure()
    fig,axes=plt.subplots(len(funcs))
    i=1
    for ax,func in zip(axes, funcs):
    #    plt.subplot(len(funcs),1,i)
        x1,T1=func(dt,dx,tm,xm,C)
        plotlays, plotcols = [2], ["black","red"]
        lines = []
        ax=plt.axes(xlim=(0,1),ylim=(-1.1,1.1))
        line,=ax.plot([],[],lw=2)
        for index in range(2):
            lobj = ax.plot([],[],lw=2,color=plotcols[index])[0]
            lines.append(lobj)

        def init():
            for line in lines:
                line.set_data([],[])
            return lines

        def animate(i):
            x=x1
            y=T1[i]
            y2=T2[i]
            xlist=[x,x]
            ylist=[y,y2]

            for lnum,line in enumerate(lines):
                line.set_data(xlist[lnum],ylist[lnum])
            return lines

        anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=np.shape(T1)[0],interval=20,blit=False)

        plt.title('%s' % func.__name__)
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('T')
        i+=1

    plt.show()



    return



def finit(x):
    if 0<=x<=.1:
        return np.sin(10*np.pi*x)
    else:
        return 0

def FTCS(dt,dx,tm,xm,C):
    x=np.arange(0,xm+dx,dx)
    t=np.arange(0,tm+dt,dt)
    lx=len(x)
    lt=len(t)
    T=np.zeros([lt,lx])
    for i in range(0,lx):
        T[0,i]=finit(x[i])
    for n in range(0,lt-1):
        for j in range(1,lx-1):
            T[n+1,j]=T[n,j]-.5*C*(T[n,j+1]-T[n,j-1])
    return x,T

def upwind(dt,dx,tm,xm,C):
    x=np.arange(0,xm+dx,dx)
    t=np.arange(0,tm+dt,dt)
    lx=len(x)
    lt=len(t)
    T=np.zeros([lt,lx])
    for i in range(0,lx):
        T[0,i]=finit(x[i])
    for n in range(0,lt-1):
        for j in range(1,lx-1):
            T[n+1,j]=(1-C)*T[n,j]+C*T[n,j-1]
    return x,T

def exact(dt,dx,tm,xm,C):
    x=np.arange(0,xm+dx,dx)
    t=np.arange(0,tm+dt,dt)
    u=C*dx/dt
    T=np.zeros([len(t),len(x)])
    for n in range(0,len(t)):
        for j in range(0,len(x)):
            if u*t[n]<x[j]<=u*t[n]+.1:
                T[n,j]=np.sin(10*np.pi*(x[j]-u*t[n]))
            else: T[n,j]=0
    return T

plot(*arguments,FTCS,upwind)
```

Comment: Let your plot function take a list of functions `plot(..., funcs=[func1, func2,..])`. Create as many axes as you have functions, `fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(funcs))`. Then iterate over the functions and axes, `for ax, func in zip(axes, funcs):` Do so for creating the lines as well as when animating them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sorry but it doesn't work. It only shows the animation of the last function. I posted edited code. Did I do it right? I'm not sure which portion of code I should put in loop and which I shouldn't.

Comment: I think        anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=np.shape(T1)[0],interval=20,blit=False) This part is problem, because fig refers to the whole figure. But I cannot put it out of loop because I made animate for each axes.

Comment: Neither the animation, nor the functions should be inside the loop. Rather you'd have a loop inside the animating function.